Error when deploying Cloud Functions for Firebase: TypeError: functions.region is not a function
I have a Firebase project which uses a mix of Cloud Functions 1st Gen and Cloud Functions 2st Gen.
I recently updated both the Firebase CLI and SDK with the following commands
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
as advised in the Cloud Functions documentation and now I get the following error when deploying:

TypeError: functions.region is not a function

How to solve this problem?

Since the default entry point changed from v1 to v2 and there's no gen2 versions of onCreate() and onDelete() you'll have to change your import to now explicity pull in v1 for onCreate() i.e. change import * as functions from 'firebase-functions' to import * as functions from 'firebase-functions/v1'.
See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1383 for more details.

In my case, I am using the require syntax, so changing const functions = require("firebase-functions") to const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1")  did the trick. Thanks!

The problem most probably comes from the fact that you updated the firebase-functions package from a v5.x.x version to a v6.x.x version.
As mentioned in the releases notes, v6.0.0 introduces the following breaking change and this is the cause of your error:

Breaking: Change default entrypoint of the firebase-functions package
to v2 instead of v1

The best solution is to do as described in the release notes, i.e. change the default entry point of the firebase-functions package to v2.
Another solution is to revert back to the last v5 version, i.e. v5.1.1.
